# How do I stop the code from repeating after a certain number of times?

Tags: python, python-3.x

(I'm new to programming) I was set a task where I had to ask the user how many people will be coming to a party. If the number is 10 or lower I ask them who they are inviting. After each input, I tell that that person is invited. This should be repeated until it reaches the number that the user-inputted when asked how many were invited

The code:

```
party = (input("How many people are you inviting to the party?:"))

if int((party)) <= 10:
    guest_list = []
    while True:
        guest_name = input("Enter guest name: ").split()
        print(guest_name[0] + " has been invited")
    
        for guest_name in party:
            break
    
   
else:
   print("Too many people!")
```

The problem is that code keeps repeating after the number inputted by the user

Comment: Instead of `while True:`, you want a loop that will iterate a fixed number of times. Perhaps consider `for _ in range(party):`, which will iterate `party` many times.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a while loop and a walrus operator to first get the number of members for the party. if the number is more than 10, it will keep asking for an answer that is less than or equal to 10.

To understand more about the walrus operator, please review this [link](https://realpython.com/lessons/assignment-expressions/)

Once you have the number, then iterate thru the loop for those many times and append to the list. You can do it with a for loop or a while loop.

```
while (party := int(input("How many people are you inviting to the party?:"))) > 10:
    print ('too many people')

guest_list = []
print (party)
while party > 0:
    guest_name = input("Enter guest name: ")
    guest_list.append(guest_name)
    print(guest_name + " has been invited")
    party -= 1

print (guest_list)
```

Output:

```
How many people are you inviting to the party?:16
too many people
How many people are you inviting to the party?:11
too many people
How many people are you inviting to the party?:3
3
Enter guest name: a
a has been invited
Enter guest name: b
b has been invited
Enter guest name: c
c has been invited
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

To wrap the while loop with a try-except, use this:

```
while True:
    try:
        while (party := int(input("How many people are you inviting to the party?:"))) > 10:
            print ('too many people')
        break
    except:
        print ('Enter a numeric value')
```

Output of this will be:

```
How many people are you inviting to the party?:a
Enter a numeric value
How many people are you inviting to the party?:b
Enter a numeric value
How many people are you inviting to the party?:c
Enter a numeric value
How many people are you inviting to the party?:3
3
Enter guest name: a
a has been invited
Enter guest name: b
b has been invited
Enter guest name: c
c has been invited
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: If you want to ensure that the input is always a number, you can wrap the first while loop within a try-except and force the user to enter numeric values only.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
party = (input("How many people are you inviting to the party?:"))

# Empty guest list
guest_list = []

if int(party) > 10:
    print("Too many people!")
else:
    # Empty guest list
    guest_list = []

    # Guest count of zero.
    guest_count = 0

    # While our guest_count is less than the target number.
    # (Since we are using a zero starting value, 0 - 9 should
    # be 10 guests.
    while guest_count < 10:

        # Accept user input
        guest_name = input("Enter guest name: ")

        # Check that the user entered a value.
        if (len(guest_name) > 0 or not guest_name is None):
            # Strip off whitespace, append to guest_list
            guest_list.append(guest_name.strip())

            # Print the last name added to the list with [-1]
            print(guest_list[-1] + " has been invited")

            # Increment our count
            guest_count += 1


print(len(guest_list) + " have been invited")
```

Comment: `while len(guest_list) <= 10:` will always prompt the user to invite 10 guests, even if earlier they only specified they were inviting fewer. Should probably be `while len(guest_list) <= int(party)`. (Or, because we're using `int(party)` multiple times now, storing that as a variable itself.)

Comment: Hmm...good point.  Moving out of the 'if' statement might work.  I didn't really test this,t bh.

Answer (score 1):

You are new to programming, then refer this smallest and simplest code.

```
no_of_guest = (int(input("How many people are you inviting to the party?:")))

if no_of_guest > 10:
    print("Too many people!")
else:  
    for i in range(no_of_guest):
        guest_name = input("Enter guest name: ")
        print(guest_name + " has been invited")
```